# Display arabic text correctly on chrome

Tags: google-chrome, browser, encoding, arabic, fusioncharts

[image: Arabic display on browsers]

(link for the picture http://d.pr/i/SCks just in case..)

On the three browsers above, the arabic text is well displayed.

On Chrome (V 15) bellow, it's a bit not well organized.

What seems to be the problem ?

PS: i'm using Fusioncharts

EDIT:

That's how I'm writing it:

```
echo '<set label="' .  addslashes($label) . ' - \' + value_' . $i . ' + \'% (' . $label_value . ') " value="' . $data_pie['nb'] . '" />\';' . "\n";
```

Comment: Please post some code related to setting the text in the charts. Also, are you setting an encoding type anywhere?

Comment: Set the U200E and U200F characters (LTR and RTL markers respectively) before and after your text. This will tell the rendering engine that everything in between must be rendered LTR.

Comment: @webnoob nothing really special about how I write it (I updated the post and included the code)

Comment: @Ansari I tried to use RLM as described in this page http://www.w3.org/WAI/PA/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS-20070910/H34.html but it doesn't mean to change anything.
I've done ` &#8207;(' . $label_value . ') &#8207; `

Comment: Hi, I think this issue is specific to the chrome version 15. I have tested in latest chrome. Its working fine now.